# Android: Keyboard not showing up in window manager dialog within service

Tags: focus

I show a custom dialog within a service that contains an editText. The problem is that the soft keyboard does not appear when focusing the editText.

Service.java

```
screenParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LOCAL_FOCUS_MODE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    screenParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    screenParams.x = 0;
    screenParams.y = 0;
    textLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    editText.requestFocus();
    windowManager.updateViewLayout(screen, screenParams);
```

layout.xml

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="@string/newText"
   android:inputType="textAutoComplete|text"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```